# How to Hide Unix Executable Files in VSCode (Mac)

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code

Every time I run a C++ file in VSCode, a Unix Executable File is generated. I would like to hide them in VSCode to prevent them from showing up in my sidebar. Does anyone know any way to achieve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use an extension like CodeRunner in VS Code

Comment: I already have the CodeRunner extension, but the file still appears.

Comment: Use the `files.exclude` setting.